# UI Bootstrap for Angular with 'collapse' directive not calling expandDone()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using UI Bootstrap for Angular (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) in a project, and I've created a directive that wraps the `collapse` directive from UI Bootstrap as follows:

```
app.directive( 'arSection', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
   return {
      template: '<div class="section" ng-class="{\'collapsed\': collapsed, \'open\': !collapsed}">' +
                '    <h4 ng-click="toggleCollapsed()">' +
                '        <span class="dropdown-ctrl" ng-class="{\'icon-chevron-right\': collapsed, \'icon-chevron-down\': !collapsed}"></span>{{title}}' +
                '    </h4>' +
                '    <div collapse="collapsed" class="section-content">' +
                '        <div ng-transclude></div>' +
                '        <div class="clear"></div>' +
                '    </div>' +
                '</div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: true,
      transclude: true,
      replace: true,
      link: function( scope, elem, attrs ){
         scope.title = attrs.title;

          // Toggle the open/closed state and save it away
          scope.toggleCollapsed = function() {
              scope.collapsed = !scope.collapsed;
          };

          scope.collapsed = true;
         }
      }
   };
} ] );
```

This mostly works, in that clicking the `h4` element causes the `div` below it to expand and collapse, however, when expanding the `div`, the `expandDone()` method in UI Bootstrap (see below) is not called when the animation is complete.

```
function expandDone() {
  element.removeClass('collapsing');
  element.addClass('collapse in');
  element.css({height: 'auto'});
}
```

This means that `height: auto` is never set on my div, so when my content grows, the div does not grow and some of the content is cut off.

The `collapseDone()` method also never gets called when collapsing.

Now, if I click onto another element in the app (outside the arSection), the `collapseDone()` and `expandDone()` methods get called!

It seems that they were queued up to run, but from my understanding, these methods are only called when an apply/digest occurs for the `collapse` directive.  Clicking on another component seems to indirectly trigger an apply/digest that reaches the collapse directive, so the queued callbacks are finally made, but much too late.

What I don't understand is how to trigger the apply/digest immediately after the animation is done so that `collapseDone()` and `expandDone()` get called at the right time.

I'm guessing it has something to do with Angular scopes or watches, but can't quite see the link I'm missing.

**UPDATE:** *I've put together a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/g2nZz6E6MJRQwM3lV8Xw) with this `arSection` directive, but it works as expected.  Click the Section One header to animate it open.  Then click the content to make it bigger.  The Section Two header moves down.  In my actual project though, the Section Two header stays where it is, even though the content in Section One gets bigger.  The bigger content is just cut off.*

*If you inspect the HTML as it runs, you can see the "collapsing" class get added and removed to the div as it animates.  The "collapsing" class does get added in my actual code, but it doesn't get removed (at least not until I click somewhere that triggers the apply/digest).*

Comment: Could you tell me which browser and which version of it you tried this on ?

Comment: Chrome Version 40.0.2214.91 (64-bit) is the main one I work on.

Comment: In your project you might be having some style rules overriding. Compare the applied styles using the style console between your app and plunker.

Comment: Super curious as to why you're not using the accordion built into angular ui?

Comment: This is an Angular project I took over from another developer, so I'm not sure if there was a reason for writing this over accordion, but it does seem like it should be possible to use accordion in place of this directive.  I'll take a look tomorrow.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised though if I run into a similar issue with the animation in accordion.  There seems to be something stopping the animation completion events from being triggered.

Answer (score 1):

I think Angular UI's accordion is a great use case here, but, for the sake of learning, here's something working: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/r16OWOsZbtLTW7uNjbdW?p=preview)

Using ng-init and ng-click you can avoid lots of logic and coding. No controller logic / directives needed here

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="CollapseDemoCtrl">
    <h3>Click the section headers to expand them</h3>
    <hr>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3 class="" ng-init="showContentOne=false" ng-click="showContentOne= !showContentOne">
        <i ng-class="showContentOne ? 'fa fa-angle-down' : 'fa fa-angle-right'"></i> Show Content One</h3>
        <div ng-show="showContentOne" class="well well-lg" ><h5>Tons of content one</h5></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3 class="" ng-init="showContentTwo=false" ng-click="showContentTwo=!showContentTwo">
        <i ng-class="showContentTwo ? 'fa fa-angle-down' : 'fa fa-angle-right'"></i> Show Content Two</h3>
        <div ng-show="showContentTwo" class="well well-lg" ><h5>Content!!</h5></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not seeing how this is related to my question at all.

Comment: I missed your question above, so now I see why you were posting this.

Comment: It seems either would work for you. This implementation builds off of yours. You''ll notice `ng-click` changes the variable with an assignment of a negation of the variable's current state.

Unless the inherited code had a very specific reason, i.e. an ajax call that updated values and manipulated element tags, I wouldn't use that directive.

Answer (score 0):

I arrived here after investigating why my accordions weren't automatically resizing to fit dynamic content. I was digging into the directive and noticed, like you, that `expandDone()` was not being called.

I resolved the issue by installing [ngAnimate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate), and adding it as a dependency:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);
```